# How to select elements from a list of strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

```
info = {"so96", "se35"};
toplanti = {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"ma21", 
    "mi06"}, {"ma21", "ma27"}, {"ma21", "so96"}, {"ma21", 
    "si63"}, {"ma30", "mi06"}, {"ma30", "se39"}, {"ma30", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "st51"}, {"ss88", "st52"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma25"}, {"ss88", "si63"}, {"ss88", "sr93"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "ma22"}, {"sr93", "ma16"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma12"}, {"sr93", "ma28"}, {"sr93", "se35"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma25"}, {"sr93", "se39"}, {"sr93", "ma22"}, {"sr93", 
    "st50"}, {"sr93", "ma33"}, {"sr93", "mi08"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma30"}, {"so96", "mi06"}, {"mi09", "ma27"}, {"mi09", 
    "st53"}, {"ma26", "st52"}, {"ma26", "st50"}, {"st51", 
    "se85"}, {"si63", "ag03"}, {"si63", "se85"}, {"se85", 
    "ma28"}, {"ma16", "si61"}, {"ma16", "st53"}, {"ma16", 
    "se85"}, {"ma16", "mi08"}, {"mi06", "si63"}, {"mi08", 
    "se85"}, {"ma12", "si63"}, {"ma15", "si63"}, {"ma22", 
    "si63"}, {"ma22", "se85"}, {"ma23", "se85"}, {"ma23", 
    "si63"}, {"ma25", "si63"}, {"ma25", "se85"}, {"ma27", 
    "si63"}, {"ma27", "se85"}, {"ma28", "si63"}, {"ma33", 
    "si63"}, {"ma33", "se85"}, {"se39", "si63"}, {"st50", 
    "se85"}, {"st50", "si63"}, {"st52", "se85"}, {"st52", "si63"}};
sec = Select[toplanti, IntersectingQ[#, info] &]
```

This generates a list of lists:

```
{{"ma21", "so96"}, {"sr93", "se35"}, {"so96", "mi06"}}
```

This result is not what I want.

My objective is to select all the pairs from `toplanti` that start with the elements in `info`. Therefore, the only correctly chosen pair above is `{"so96", "mi06"}`.

Comment: `Select[toplanti, MemberQ[info, #[[1]]] &]?`

Comment: `Select[toplanti, IntersectingQ[#[[{1}]], info] &]`. Also `Cases[{Alternatives @@ info, _}]@toplanti`

Comment: `Cases[toplanti, {info[[1]], _}]`

Comment: All of these comments were very useful. In my actual code, I used `Select[toplanti, IntersectingQ[#[[{1}]], info] &]` (by kglr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `toplanti` contains duplicated values, I choose a different `info`

```
info = {"ma15", "ma16"};
```

With `Select` (commented by vindobona) you get

```
Select[toplanti, MemberQ[info, #[[1]]] &]
```

{{"ma16", "si61"}, {"ma16", "st53"}, {"ma16", "se85"}, {"ma16",
"mi08"}, {"ma15", "si63"}}

The difference between the (last two) elements is difficult to see

An alternative, especially for large lists and/or repeated queries, is an `Association`.

```
a = GroupBy[toplanti, First -> Last];

KeyTake[info] @ a
```

<|"ma15" -> {"si63"}, "ma16" -> {"si61", "st53", "se85", "mi08"}|>

Some other useful query methods include

```
a["ma16"]
```

{"si61", "st53", "se85", "mi08"}

```
Lookup[info] @ a
```

{{"si63"}, {"si61", "st53", "se85", "mi08"}}

```
Lookup[{"so96", "se35"}] @ a
```

{{"mi06"}, Missing["KeyAbsent", "se35"]}

Replace `Missing` with the third argument of `Lookup`

```
Lookup[a, {"so96", "se35"}, {}]
```

{{"mi06"}, {}}

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**

```
Pick[#,StringMatchQ[info]@#[[All,1]]]&[toplanti]

(* {{so96,mi06}}  *)
```

```
info2 = {"so96", "ag03"};
Pick[#,StringMatchQ[info2]@#[[All,1]]]&[toplanti]

(* {{ag03,sr93},{ag03,ma16},{so96,mi06}} *)
```

From the documentation for [`StringMatchQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html),the following may be inferred:

```
StringMatchQ[info]@toplanti[[All,1]] ==
    (MatchQ[Alternatives@@info]/@toplanti[[All,1]])

(* True *)
```

(`StringMatchQ` threads over a list, and there is no need for `Alternatives`)

**In addition**

```
Pick[toplanti, toplanti[[All,1]],  #]&/@info

(* {{{so96,mi06}},{}} *)
```

```
Pick[toplanti, toplanti[[All,1]],  #]&/@info2

(* {{{so96,mi06}},{{ag03,sr93},{ag03,ma16}}} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Pick[#,MatchQ[#,Alternatives@@info]&/@#[[All,1]]]&@toplanti

(* {{so96,mi06}}  *)
```

```
info2 = {"so96", "ag03"};

Pick[#,MatchQ[#,Alternatives@@info2]&/@#[[All,1]]]&@toplanti

(* {{ag03,sr93},{ag03,ma16},{so96,mi06}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
info = {"so96", "se35", "ag03"};
toplanti = {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"ma21", 
    "mi06"}, {"ma21", "ma27"}, {"ma21", "so96"}, {"ma21", 
    "si63"}, {"ma30", "mi06"}, {"ma30", "se39"}, {"ma30", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "st51"}, {"ss88", "st52"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma25"}, {"ss88", "si63"}, {"ss88", "sr93"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "ma22"}, {"sr93", "ma16"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma12"}, {"sr93", "ma28"}, {"sr93", "se35"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma25"}, {"sr93", "se39"}, {"sr93", "ma22"}, {"sr93", 
    "st50"}, {"sr93", "ma33"}, {"sr93", "mi08"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma30"}, {"so96", "mi06"}, {"mi09", "ma27"}, {"mi09", 
    "st53"}, {"ma26", "st52"}, {"ma26", "st50"}, {"st51", 
    "se85"}, {"si63", "ag03"}, {"si63", "se85"}, {"se85", 
    "ma28"}, {"ma16", "si61"}, {"ma16", "st53"}, {"ma16", 
    "se85"}, {"ma16", "mi08"}, {"mi06", "si63"}, {"mi08", 
    "se85"}, {"ma12", "si63"}, {"ma15", "si63"}, {"ma22", 
    "si63"}, {"ma22", "se85"}, {"ma23", "se85"}, {"ma23", 
    "si63"}, {"ma25", "si63"}, {"ma25", "se85"}, {"ma27", 
    "si63"}, {"ma27", "se85"}, {"ma28", "si63"}, {"ma33", 
    "si63"}, {"ma33", "se85"}, {"se39", "si63"}, {"st50", 
    "se85"}, {"st50", "si63"}, {"st52", "se85"}, {"st52", "si63"}};
```

---

```
Select[toplanti, MemberQ[info, First@#] &]

PositionIndex[toplanti[[All, 1]]] // KeyTake[info] // Values // 
  Flatten // Extract[toplanti, List /@ #] &

Extract[toplanti, Position[Alternatives @@ info][toplanti[[All, 1]]]]

SequenceCases[toplanti, {{Alternatives @@ info, _}}] // Map[First]

DeleteCases[toplanti, _?(FreeQ[{Alternatives @@ info, _}])]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"so96", "mi06"}}

Answer (score 3):

```
info = {"so96", "se35", "ag03"};
toplanti = {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"ma21", 
    "mi06"}, {"ma21", "ma27"}, {"ma21", "so96"}, {"ma21", 
    "si63"}, {"ma30", "mi06"}, {"ma30", "se39"}, {"ma30", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "st51"}, {"ss88", "st52"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma25"}, {"ss88", "si63"}, {"ss88", "sr93"}, {"ss88", 
    "ma26"}, {"ss88", "ma22"}, {"sr93", "ma16"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma12"}, {"sr93", "ma28"}, {"sr93", "se35"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma25"}, {"sr93", "se39"}, {"sr93", "ma22"}, {"sr93", 
    "st50"}, {"sr93", "ma33"}, {"sr93", "mi08"}, {"sr93", 
    "ma30"}, {"so96", "mi06"}, {"mi09", "ma27"}, {"mi09", 
    "st53"}, {"ma26", "st52"}, {"ma26", "st50"}, {"st51", 
    "se85"}, {"si63", "ag03"}, {"si63", "se85"}, {"se85", 
    "ma28"}, {"ma16", "si61"}, {"ma16", "st53"}, {"ma16", 
    "se85"}, {"ma16", "mi08"}, {"mi06", "si63"}, {"mi08", 
    "se85"}, {"ma12", "si63"}, {"ma15", "si63"}, {"ma22", 
    "si63"}, {"ma22", "se85"}, {"ma23", "se85"}, {"ma23", 
    "si63"}, {"ma25", "si63"}, {"ma25", "se85"}, {"ma27", 
    "si63"}, {"ma27", "se85"}, {"ma28", "si63"}, {"ma33", 
    "si63"}, {"ma33", "se85"}, {"se39", "si63"}, {"st50", 
    "se85"}, {"st50", "si63"}, {"st52", "se85"}, {"st52", "si63"}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` and `Take`:

```
Take[Cases[{_, _}]@
SequenceSplit[Flatten@toplanti, s : {Alternatives @@ #, b_} :> s],
Length@#] &@info
```

> {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"so96", "mi06"}}

Or using `Position` and ReplacePart`:

```
pos = Position[toplanti, {a_, b_} /; And @@ UnsameQ @@@ Thread[{info, a}]];

ReplacePart[toplanti, pos -> Nothing]
```

> {{"ag03", "sr93"}, {"ag03", "ma16"}, {"so96", "mi06"}}